# Big number of pushbuttons and smart checking which is checked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have dialog:

[image: Dialog]

It contains many flat QPushButtons, QTextEdit and another QPushButton. After click on 'Get list' we can see list of checked buttons in QTextEdit.

My question is how to get this functionality in some smart way. Right now I'm checking every button:

```
    if self.ui.bq6o.isChecked():
        cards.append("Q6o")
    if self.ui.bk2o.isChecked():
        cards.append("K2o")
    if self.ui.bq3o.isChecked():
        cards.append("Q3o")
    if self.ui.bt7s.isChecked():
        cards.append("T7s")
    if self.ui.bq4o.isChecked():
        cards.append("Q4o")
    if self.ui.bt4s.isChecked():
        cards.append("T4s")
    if self.ui.b98o.isChecked():
        cards.append("98o")
    if self.ui.bjto.isChecked():
        cards.append("JTo")
    if self.ui.btt.isChecked():
        cards.append("TT")
    if self.ui.bq7o.isChecked():
        cards.append("Q7o")

    [...]
```

Obviously I can't like code like that. I was looking for some widget "button matrix" like, but without luck. I will be grateful for advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brendan suggested in the other question, you could loop through them in a single list comprehension. But one other approach is to connect each buttons toggled signal to a slot that allows them to register when they are checked.

```
# somewhere in your class
self.checkedList = set()

def buttonChecked(self, checked):
    button = self.sender()
    if checked:
        self.checkedList.add(button)
    else:
        if button in self.checkedList:
            self.checkedList.remove(button)

# when you create a new button
button.toggled.connect(self.buttonChecked)
```

This would let you always have a set of just the checked buttons, which are self reporting. Otherwise, you would have to track them under their parent and loop to find out which are checked each time.

#### Update

Here is a another version that combines @Brendans loop and my signal suggestion. This might help in a situation where your buttons are a bit more spread out across your UI as opposed to be all under a single parent... but first assuming them all under a parent...

```
parent = dialog
for widget in parent.children():
    if isinstance(widget, QPushButton):
        widget.toggled.connect(self.buttonChecked)
```

You could repeat this in your `__init__()` for all the locations of your buttons and get them all registered to the slot.

Comment: I'm using designer to generate GUI, so it looks like that Brendan answer suit better to my needs. But thanks it as better solution when creating GUI without designer.

Comment: Sure thing. Though Brendans solution might become more complicated if your buttons end up spanning different parent widgets at some point. Then you will have to do a bit more looping over the containers. Also, you could combine Brendans suggestion and mine by looping once over all the buttons in your init and making the signal connection. From then on you would just check your small set

Comment: Indeed. I will use combination of yours solution. Thanks you once again.

Answer (score 2):

All the buttons should be children of the same widget, probably the dialog itself.  Just get a  handle to that widget to get all the child buttons, then loop through them and if they're checked, included their text.

```
parent = dialog  # or whatever
cards = [widget.text() for widget in parent.children() if isinstance(widget, QPushButton) and widget.isChecked()]
```

You may need to include some code in the if statement to exclude the "Get List" button, or any other pushbuttons in your dialog that could be set to "checked" but shouldn't be included in cards list.